# Javascript function not triggered by button click of asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, buttonclick

Trying to trigger javascript function on click of asp.net button , but it won't work. I tried `usesubmitbehaviour=false` and trying adding return to function also.

Here is my code snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkout() {
        alert("test")
        var stripe = Stripe("*********")

        var button = document.getElementById("Button1");
        stripe.redirecttocheckout({    
            sessionId = document.getElementById('<%= test.ClientID %>').value
        })    
    }          
</script>
```

and function call from button click of asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID ="Button1" runat ="server"  
    class="btn btn-secondary bt-dark bt-darkregister"  
    style="width:210px" 
    Text="Continue to secure payment"   
    OnclientClick=" return checkout()" />
```

Comment: Could just comment "var button = document.getElementById("Button1");" part but still wont work

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use OnclientClick and not OnClick?

You can try using it in thr following manner and tell me what happens?

```
  <asp:Button id="Button1"
       Text="Click here for greeting..."
       OnClick="GreetingBtn_Click" 
       runat="server"/>
```

Comment: i suppose this works to call function in backend not in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide more information.

Move your script block to inside of the form /form tags

And

```
OnClientClick="checkout();return false;"
```

And you js code looks wrong too.

Try this:

```
<script>
  function checkout() {
    alert("test");
  }          
</script>
```

So your js code is missing the ending ";" on each line of js